# MS Project. VB, Vb.NET. Application.CustomFieldValueListGetItem - How to get all Items?

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

How can i get all items in List?

Function "CustomFieldValueListGetItem" gets the elements only **by index**.

I don't know the last index. Can't find such property or function that returns it.

Is there any function like "GetAllItems as Array or Collection"? (MSDN didn't help)

So, to get that, i've wrote code, it works, but i don't like it.

```
 Dim MSPApp = oProjAct.Application
 Dim GetStr As String
 Dim CurrentArray(0)
 For y = 1 To 1500
   Try
     GetStr = MSPApp.CustomFieldValueListGetItem(PjCustomField.pjCustomTaskText2, PjValueListItem.pjValueListValue, y)
     ReDim Preserve CurrentArray(UBound(CurrentArray) + 1)
     CurrentArray(UBound(CurrentArray)) = GetStr
   Catch
       Exit For 'so if error - that's the last item.
   End Try
  Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously pointed out, there is no Count method since there is no collection object exposed in the API. All the API offers is the [CustomFieldValueListGetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.customfieldvaluelistgetitem) method to reach into that hidden collection object of custom field list values.

Here is a variation of your code that, at least, reads a little better:

```
Dim ListValues As New List(Of String)
Try
    Dim idx As Int32 = 0
    Do While True AndAlso idx < 10000
        idx += 1
        ListValues.Add(ProjApp.CustomFieldValueListGetItem(PjCustomField.pjCustomTaskText2, PjValueListItem.pjValueListValue, idx))
    Loop
Catch NoMoreItems As System.Exception
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Project object model doesn't provide a count property that can be used as the basis for a loop. As such, sometimes you just have to "bunt" and that's what you have done with your simple code. It works, relish that, and move on.